# Error when adding Firebase Analytics to Android project with appcompat-v7:28.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have a working Android project that i am trying to add Firebase analytics. As soon as i add `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'` to my graddle it gives me the error at the end of the post. I tried several suggestins i found on other post like adding "-alpha1" at the end of appcompat line but it was a rabit hole. I also did what the error suggests but the same another rabbit hole. 
Does any one have any other suggestions? 
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.track.live"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.4'
    implementation 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.1'
    implementation 'me.jahirfiquitiva:FABsMenu:1.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute
>   application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:14:5-52:19 to override.

Comment: did you add firebase-core lib?

Comment: Not sure, I did everything that Firebase page said. Just this last step gave me problems.

Comment: maybe you just followed the steps for analytics lib but before that you should check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup and also recommend to use androidX instead of com.android.support. google it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the latest version of firebase analytics. Firebase migrated to androidx in June 2019, from the docs:

> This release is a MAJOR version update and includes breaking changes.
>
> With this release, libraries are migrated from the Android Support Libraries to the Jetpack (AndroidX) Libraries.
>
> The updated libraries will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:
>
> Upgrade com.android.tools.build:gradle to v3.2.1 or later.
>
> Upgrade compileSdkVersion to 28 or later.
>
> Update your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX); follow the instructions in Migrating to AndroidX.

The above is applied from version 17.0.0 of firebase analytics.

You can find more info here :

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2019-06-17

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: Thanks, I'll do this then. Keep you posted

Comment: Migrating to AndroidX fixed my issue and it was scary easy!

Answer (score 0):

You have a suggestion inside an error message "Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory""
But my opinion and advice - move to androidX

Comment: Yes I tried that suggestion but it gave me more and more errors.

Comment: So, just migrate to AndroidX

Comment: Google forces us to use the latest libraries as possible.